# How is the toString() method of Object class compiled in java?

Tags: java, oop

Object class is the base class of every class, i.e, every class extends Object class. 
There is a public String toString() method in Object class and the same method is present in String class even.
Now, the String class also extends Object class and the method toString returns a String type.

My question is-: While compiling the Object class, it will search for the String.class and the String class will search for Object.class creating a type of interdependency. How this dependency is resolved? How the compilation mechanism works? Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: I don't know how buy Java supports this kind of reference loop in any class. That's why you can't compile a java file without the classpath. The compiler inspect other classes when needed.

Comment: in java there is nothing wrong with having a class A import B; and a class B import A; (and in other languages there are forward declarations)

Comment: It´s the same as compiling two other classes that reference each other.

Comment: Well, this is not java specific....C# also accepts such code: `public class Class1
    {
        public Class2 giveClass2() {
            return new Class2();
        }
    }

    public class Class2 : Class1
    {

    }`

Comment: Well, I am not saying it is wrong. I am asking how the compiler compiles. The mechanism behind the compilation, as it should not be able to locate the other class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java compiler is a [Multi-Pass Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-pass_compiler). This means that there are incremental steps in the compile procedure. While compiling `Object`, it uses a temporary representation of `String` so to allow `Object` to compile.

You can compare the temporary representation with some sort of hidden interface. The compiler compiles to that interface. Only at runtime the compiled parts come together - the compiler doesn't need a fully compiled class to compile another class, only an abstraction of it.

Comment: Although it does not fit perfectly, one could add a reference to the steps of compiling and [linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) that is done for other languages. The compiler "assumes" that it has everything that needs. The linker will actually "resolve the links" (and spill out all these *undefined reference* errors)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, while you write such codes:

```
public class Class1 
{
 public Class2 giveClass2()
 {
  return new Class2();
 }
}
public class Class2 : Class1 { }
```

It compiles correctly because it does not instantiate anything. The compiler just checks if the types you use is defined or not.

However, if you write it as below:

```
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1(){
            aClass2 = new Class2();
        }
        public Class2 aClass2;
    }

    public class Class2 : Class1
    {

    }
```

This will also get compiled, but it causes Stack-overflow at run time because then the cyclic dependencies impact.